# How can I paste the column name into a new column depending on another column's value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to paste the name of a column ("diagnosis") into a new column ("suspected diagnosis" or susp_dx) if it has a 1 in it:

```
practice <- data.frame(record_id = 1:5,
                  susp_inflamm = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                  susp_bacteria = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  susp_virus = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                  susp_fungus = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

Some rows will have more than one diagnosis. practice$susp_dx would therefore contain susp_inflamm and susp_bacteria for record 1 for example.

```
practice$susp_dx <- names(practice[,c(2:5)])[which(practice[,c(2:5)] == 1)]
```

I've tried the above based on previous answers on here but it seems to apply column-wise or cycle through.

Ideally I'd prefer to use dplyr rather than base r to do it. I've tried the line below but starts_with needs a selecting function. I've tried using across to sum a row and then later mutate but that doesn't really do what I want.

```
susp_practice <- practice %>% 
  mutate(susp_dx = ifelse(where(is.double) & (starts_with("susp")) == 1), names(.), 0))
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you include the exact output you want to see above based on the input given?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960010/get-column-name-that-matches-specific-row-value-in-dataframe ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977631/find-all-column-names-where-any-specified-row-will-have-the-cell-value-of-1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945291/for-each-row-get-column-names-where-data-is-equal-to-a-certain-value might be helpful to you.

Comment: @benson23 I was looking for those, but there are no good dplyr examples in there ... I hadn't found one, though I know this is not an uncommon question ...

Comment: Thanks all- the answer below gives a good illustration of the output I was after TimBiegeleisen. @benson23- thanks, I'd seen all but the last of those but couldn't get it to work accurately. r2evans- judging from the response below, I guess it can be clunky but clearly a need for it. I'm currently using an even clunkier way of doing it and thought I was just being naive but I think it's probably a needed but tricky function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` by itself is not well-suited for this without reshaping the data back and forth, which makes the presence of other columns something to deal with, and larger data will be a bother.

However, this can work:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
practice |>
  pivot_longer(-record_id) |>
  filter(value > 0) |>
  summarize(.by = record_id, quux = paste(name, collapse = ", ")) |>
  full_join(practice, by = "record_id")
# # A tibble: 5 × 6
#   record_id quux                        susp_inflamm susp_bacteria susp_virus susp_fungus
#       <int> <chr>                              <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1         1 susp_inflamm, susp_bacteria            1             1          0           0
# 2         2 susp_virus                             0             0          1           0
# 3         3 susp_fungus                            0             0          0           1
# 4         4 susp_inflamm                           1             0          0           0
# 5         5 NA                                     0             0          0           0
```

We can make a bespoke function to do this within `dplyr`:

```r
fun <- function(x) apply(x > 0, 1, function(z) paste(names(x)[z], collapse = ", "))
practice |>
  mutate(quux = fun(pick(starts_with("susp_"))))
#   record_id susp_inflamm susp_bacteria susp_virus susp_fungus                        quux
# 1         1            1             1          0           0 susp_inflamm, susp_bacteria
# 2         2            0             0          1           0                  susp_virus
# 3         3            0             0          0           1                 susp_fungus
# 4         4            1             0          0           0                susp_inflamm
# 5         5            0             0          0           0
```

In `data.table`-speak, this is fairly simple using the `fun` defined above.

```r
library(data.table)
practice[, quux := fun(.SD), .SDcols = patterns("^susp_")]
#    record_id susp_inflamm susp_bacteria susp_virus susp_fungus                        quux
#        <int>        <num>         <num>      <num>       <num>                      <char>
# 1:         1            1             1          0           0 susp_inflamm, susp_bacteria
# 2:         2            0             0          1           0                  susp_virus
# 3:         3            0             0          0           1                 susp_fungus
# 4:         4            1             0          0           0                susp_inflamm
# 5:         5            0             0          0           0
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give this a go. If you were to do it without dplyr, would you just use base R? The real dataset is much larger and more complicated so if you have any additional thoughts/tips I'd be grateful for your time.

Comment: If it's "large-ish" data, I often recommend considering `data.table`, it can be more memory-efficient. I'll see if I can get to it later today.